# How do I print the date by clicking a button in Qt Designer?

Tags: python, forms, qt, pyqt4

I am trying to create a form through Qt designer that will be frequently updated by the user. I want to allow the user to select a date and save that date to keep track of when the form was last updated.[The image is what my form currently looks like. If the user clicks the 'save date' button, the date selected just above will be saved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qtdh.png)

I am using python to program this, and currently this is what my code looks like:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(785, 596)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.comboBox_2 = QtGui.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox_2, 18, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox"))
        self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 19, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_3"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.textBrowser_3 = QtGui.QTextBrowser(Form)
        self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser_3"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser_3, 13, 0, 1, 2)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtGui.QTextBrowser(Form)
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser_2, 10, 0, 1, 2)
        self.PrintDate_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.PrintDate_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("PrintDate_btn"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.PrintDate_btn, 16, 0, 1, 1)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 7, 0, 1, 2)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 11, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem3 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem3, 12, 0, 1, 1)
        self.dateEdit = QtGui.QDateEdit(Form)
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dateEdit"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.dateEdit, 14, 0, 1, 1)


        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Enterprise Passport", None))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("Form", "1st Gen university", None))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "award1", None))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "award2", None))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "award3", None))
        self.PrintDate_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "SaveDate", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Activities", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Achievements", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Awards", None))
        self.PrintDate_btn.clicked.connect(self.PrintDate)



    def PrintDate(self):
        print(Ui_Form.setupUi(self.dateEdit))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have tried all sorts of things, but I can't seem to get it to save or even print the date selected when pressing the button. Could somebody tell me how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  def PrintDate(self):
        print self.dateEdit.text()
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you added a few words of explanation. Also, the code you have given is correct, but it will only work with python2 (and it looks like the OP may be using python3).

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice OP is using python3. 
The explanation would be  -  documentation is incomplete. Easiest way to check object functionality is to call dir()